# Label issue with Bottom Navigation View

Tags: android, android-support-library, bottomnavigationview

I am facing a weird issue with the newly released `Bottom Navigation View` (in the Design Support Library). When you have more than 3 tabs (I have 5 tabs), and `don't keep activities` is enabled in the developer options on the device or emulator, and you start a new activity on top of the activity where you have the bottom navigation view (perhaps from one of your fragments), and close it after some seconds (wait a little bit to make sure the old activity is killed by Android), the labels for all tabs in the bottom navigation view change to the last tab's label, i.e. you have a single label, the one for the last tab, repeated in all tabs. The issue is weird because the menu is inflated from the menu xml file in which the icons and labels are defined, but the icons are shown properly while the labels are not. I appreciate any help.

I reported this bug. If you face the same issue, please star the bug [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=227737) to help with the bug fix prioritisation.

Comment: What do you mean by improperly shown? Can you post screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the freezeText attribute. If you have enabled freezeText globally (for all of your TextViews) in your styles.xml, like this:

```
<style name="Text" parent="android:Widget.TextView">
  <item name="android:freezesText">true</item>
</style>
```

you need to disable this attribute on the TextViews used by BottomNavigationView since it caches the TextViews in a pool and reuses them from the pool. There is also a bug with this View: it always returns `true` even if the listener (of type `OnNavigationItemSelectedListener`) returns `false`. That causes issues when you don't want to select the new tab if listener returns false (based on some condition check e.g. if the user is not logged in). That also can be fixed by invoking the listener's onNavigationItemSelected() directly. We added the following helper method to address both issues:

```
private void setNavigationItemSelectedListener(BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener listener) {
  BottomNavigationMenuView menuView = (BottomNavigationMenuView) bottomNavigationView.getChildAt(0);
  for (int i = 0; i < menuView.getChildCount(); i++) {
    BottomNavigationItemView itemView = (BottomNavigationItemView) menuView.getChildAt(i);      

    // Labels are re-used from a pool, if you have global freeze text enabled, this causes state problems
    ((TextView) itemView.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.smallLabel)).setFreezesText(false);
    ((TextView) itemView.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.largeLabel)).setFreezesText(false);

    // Workaround for BottomNavigationMenu bug where it selects the item even if the listener returns false
    itemView.setOnClickListener(click -> listener.onNavigationItemSelected(itemView.getItemData()));
  }
}
```